# Google LeaderBoard not working when application is published on play store

Tags: android, game-center-leaderboard

I have implemented Google LeaderBoard in my android application. It is working fine when it is not published (testing mode) but it is showing "application is incorrectly configured".
here is the Apk file : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fastandfuriouscopter.rs
it work well while i run the app from Eclipse.

Comment: DId you publish the leaderboard as well?

Comment: And you said it runs correct with eclipse. I wonder which SHA you put while creating the game. You should put the SHA from the keystore that you intend to publish the app.

Comment: @Farooq : yup i have published

Comment: @Farooq, i have puted SHA1 which i generate from CMD , i also feel that when i sign the apk at last page its show different SHA1 ..

Comment: While using the command line did you use the correct Keystore? or the debug keystore?

Comment: Yes the SHA1 after signing should have been put there. Create a new game with that SHA in GAME SERVICES section.